# Autohotkey Regex Lookbehind Assertion

Tags: regex, autohotkey

In my script `'matchfile` is a filename with or without an extension.

In my text below, there may or may not be `[AnyText]`, and the text between the brackets could be any alphnumeric characters.

How can I match:

```
some text
\includescore{something}
\includescore{something.ext}
%\includescore{doNOT.match}
\includescore[AnyText]{something}
\includescore[AnyText]{something.ext}
more text
```

So far I have this:

```
regexmatch(searchthis, "mi)(?<=(?<!%)\\includescore\{|(?<!%)\\includescore\[\w\]\{)[\w\s\.\+'#-]+\.?[\w\s\.\+'#-]+(?=.*\})", matchfile)
```

But that can only match:

```
\includescore{something}
\includescore{something.extension}
\includescore[a]{something}
```

And I don't want to match if the line is started with a `%`.

My first idea is to use `w+` but Autohotkey won't allow for the unquantified lookbehind.

Actually, I don't even care about matching the square brackets.  I only have to match `\includescore`, the `matchfile` and the curly brackets.

Is there another way to do this, or do I need to do multiple regex calls?

Comment: Where does `includescore` come from in your regex? Please provide some real input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this:

```
;Fetch the uncommented inclusion line
regexmatch(searchthis, "mi)(?<=(?<!%)\\includescore).*?{(.*?)}", matchfile)

;Now pull out the bracketed item
regexmatch(matchinclusion, "i)(?:\[.*\])", includeparam)        ;get the parameter

;now pull out the filename with/without the extension
regexmatch(matchinclusion, "i)(?<={)(.*)(?=})", inclusionfile)  ;get the tex name
```

It matches on all counts, and excludes the line commented with the `%`.

In Autohotkey, it matches every instance, and only returns the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is what you want:

`mi)^(?:(?<!%)\\includescore(?:\[\w*\])?(?:\{[\w.]*\})|.*matchfile(?:\.\w*)?)`

`\includescore(?:\[\w*\])?(?:\{[\w.]*\})` will capture all includescores with optional `[AnyText]` and obligatory {*something*}.

In case 'matchfile' is not at the beginning of a line, I added `.*`, and optional extension will be captured with `(?:\.\w*)?)`

Comment: I can't use 'matchfile' in the regex because it is an ahk variable.  I have match the *pattern* of the filename contained in it.

Comment: If you provide an example of such text with matchfile in it, I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you are understanding; `matchfile` could be anything like in my examples:  `something` or `something.ext`.  That's okay; I think I figured out what to do.  +1 for being so willing to help.